# HTML In a hook_menu title callback

Tags: 6, routes

I'm trying to insert a span class around some text in title callback. It passes through a `t()` function so all the html is escaped.

Is there a way round this?

My code is:

```
function custom_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['discussion'] = array(
    'title' => 'Discussion',
    'title callback' => 'custom_module_title',
    'page callback' => 'custom_module_tester1',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'document-menu',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'options' => array('attributes' => array('class' => 'discussion')),
    'weight' => 10,
  );

  return $items;
}
function custom_module_title() {
  $discussionnid = custom_module_postexist(3);
  if ($discussionnid) {
    return 'Discussion <span class="discussionnumber">85</span>';
  }
  else {
    return 'Discussion';
  }

}
```

Comment: You can do this in your theme as it is theming related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML in the title is escaped because [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) gets the title using the following code:

```
// Construct page title
  if (drupal_get_title()) {
    $head_title = array(strip_tags(drupal_get_title()), variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'));
  }
```

[drupal_get_title()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_title/6) then contains the following code:

```
function drupal_get_title() {
  $title = drupal_set_title();

  // during a bootstrap, menu.inc is not included and thus we cannot provide a title
  if (!isset($title) && function_exists('menu_get_active_title')) {
    $title = check_plain(menu_get_active_title());
  }

  return $title;
}
```

The title is escaped from that function.

As far as I know, the content of `<title>` should not contain HTML tags; that is the reason it is escaped.

In the [W3C specifications for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2) is reported the following text:

> Titles may contain character entities (for accented characters, special characters, etc.), but may not contain other markup (including comments). Here is a sample document title:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
>    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <HTML>
> <HEAD>
> <TITLE>A study of population dynamics</TITLE>
> <!-- other head elements -->
> </HEAD>
> <BODY>
> <!-- document body -->
> </BODY>
> </HTML>
> ```

In [Changed Elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/#changed-elements) it's not reported any changes between HTML 5 and HTML 4 about the `<title>` tag.

In Drupal 7, you could set the title with [`drupal_set_title($title, PASS_THROUGH)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7), but the documentation says:

> Only set to [PASS_THROUGH](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/PASS_THROUGH/7) if you have already removed any possibly dangerous code from `$title` using a function like [check_plain()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) or [filter_xss()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss/7). With this flag the string will be passed through unchanged.

`PASS_THROUGH` is used to avoid the title is filtered twice, not to filter the title at all.

Then, using `drupal_set_title()` is not possible from the title callback; you should set it in a different place. I would not suggest doing so, though.

Comment: I was getting confused, title also changes the menu link text as well. I'm only interested in that not the actual page title. I didn't realise page title and link text were the same in hook_menu(). I need to look elsewhere to change the link text.

Comment: You need a way to have a page title that is different from the `<head>` title. Even if you are able to get the HTML not escaped in the page title, the `<head>` title would still contain escaped HTML tags.

Comment: I believe OP mean the `title` key in the menu item array, the one that is rendered in the page, not the `title` HTML attribute.

Comment: @GabrielR. The title reported in the menu item array is the title of the page, and becomes part of the HTML title shown in `<title>`. What I reported in this answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
drupal_set_title('your html title',PASS_THROUGH)
```

before to render your page.

`PASS_THROUGH` = Flag for `drupal_set_title();`, text has already been sanitized.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to display the weight of the menu item right next to the link. Since it seems problematic to insert HTML in the link title itself, I chose a different approach:

Add an extra attribute to your links and show it using CSS

```
$items['discussion'] = array(
  // ... all the other properties
  // Our special attributes:
  'options' => array(
    'attributes' => customAttr()
  ),
);

function customAttr() {
  $discussionnid = custom_module_postexist(3);
  if ($discussionnid) {
    return array(
      'class' => 'discussion',
      'data-discussionnumber' => 85
    );
  }
  else {
    return array(
      'class' => 'discussion'
    );
  }
}
```

This returns a link like:

```
<a class="discussion" data-discussionnumber="85" href="yourHref">yourTitle</a>
```

Now you can add the following CSS:

```
#document-menu a:after {
  content: attr(data-discussionnumber);
  /* your custom styles */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Define `title callback` a function to replace `t()`

e.g.

```
<?php
function node_menu() {
  $items['node/%node'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'node_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(1),
    'page callback' => 'node_page_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}

/**
* Title callback.
*/
function node_page_title($nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  return "<span>" . $node->title . "</span>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I'm using, even though I'm defining a title callback the html is still escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived here looking for the answer for drupal 7. (I don't know if it works for drupal 6).
You can add to the "options" array "html" => "true". This parameter will be passed to the l() saying to not parse the html tags. Use with precaution, because it's dangerous.

from [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7):

> "options": An array of options to be passed to l() when generating a link from this menu item. Note that the "options" parameter has no effect on MENU_LOCAL_TASK, MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, and MENU_LOCAL_ACTION items.

and from [l](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)():

> 'attributes': An associative array of HTML attributes to apply to the anchor tag. If element 'class' is included, it must be an array; 'title' must be a string; other elements are more flexible, as they just need to work in a call to drupal_attributes($options['attributes']).
>
> > 'html' (default FALSE): Whether $text is HTML or just plain-text. For example, to make an image tag into a link, this must be set to TRUE, or you will see the escaped HTML image tag. $text is not sanitized if 'html' is TRUE. The calling function must ensure that $text is already safe.

would be like that:

```
 function custom_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['discussion'] = array(
    'title' => 'Discussion',
    'title callback' => 'custom_module_title',
    'page callback' => 'custom_module_tester1',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'document-menu',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'options' => array('attributes' => array(
       'class' => 'discussion',                //will be passed to l()
       'html' => true 
       )),
    'weight' => 10,
  );

  return $items;
  }


  function custom_module_title() {
    $discussionnid = custom_module_postexist(3);
    if ($discussionnid) {
      return 'Discussion <span class="discussionnumber">85</span>';
    }
    else {
      return 'Discussion';
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you menu item is `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` anything you specify in `'options'` won't be picked up.  The only way I could work out to get my options in was using `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()`